# XML to XSLT can open data from xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I have this two files
 XML FILE:

```
    <CadeiaHoteis>
    <Hoteis id="1">
            <codigo>458</codigo> 
            <morada>Porto</morada>
            <num_quartos>3</num_quartos>
            <piscina>Não</piscina>
            <restaurante>
                <dados>Sim</dados>
                <num_mesas>10</num_mesas>
                <num_pessoas>3</num_pessoas>
                <hora_abertura>11:30</hora_abertura>
                <hora_fechar>23:00</hora_fechar>
            </restaurante>
            <num_funcionarios>8</num_funcionarios>
    </Hoteis>
    <Hoteis id="2">
     <codigo>381</codigo> 
            <morada>Lisboa</morada>
            <num_quartos>25</num_quartos>
            <piscina>Sim</piscina>
            <restaurante> 
                <dados></dados>
                <num_mesas></num_mesas>
                <num_pessoas></num_pessoas>
                <hora_abertura></hora_abertura>
                <hora_fechar></hora_fechar>
            </restaurante>
            <num_funcionarios>6</num_funcionarios>
    </Hoteis>
```

XSLT FILE:

```
   <xsl:template match="ns:Hoteis_">
        <xsl:variable name="Hoteis/id" select="@id_hotel"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="//Hoteis/restaurante">
            <xsl:if test="dados != ' '">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center"> 
                        <xsl:value-of select= "ns:num_mesas" />
                    </td>
                    <td align="center"> 
                        <xsl:value-of select= "ns:num_pessoas" />
                    </td>
                    <td align="center"> 
                        <xsl:value-of select= "ns:hora_abertura" />
                    </td>
                    <td align="center"> 
                        <xsl:value-of select= "ns:hora_fechar" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="not(string(dados))">
                <tr>
                    <td>DONT EXIT RESTAURANT <xsl:value-of select= "@id_hotel" />  </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:if>

        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
```

i want t the restaurant data if dados is not empty but just does not show, does anyone know how I can do to show data??

Answer (score 1):

Since your source elements are unprefixed and there are some prefixed element selectors in your XSLT, I'm assuming *all* your elements belong to the same namespace (which I called `your-namespace`) and your source actually starts like this:

```
<CadeiaHoteis xmlns="your-namespace">
    <Hoteis id="1">
    ...
```

If that's not the case, then you will have to make some adjustments to the stylesheet below.

Considering all your elements belonging to that namespace, your stylesheet should declare it and map it to a prefix (`ns`). Then you should use that prefix to qualify your element selectors (or else they will not be found, and none of your tests will work). Finally, you can test for an empty `dados` element with `normalize-space(ns:dados)`. It will be better inside a `xs:choose` block since you can treat the other case in `xs:otherwise`.

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns="your-namespace" version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="ns:CadeiaHoteis">
        <table>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ns:Hoteis">
        <xsl:variable name="hoteis_id" select="@id"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="ns:restaurante">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="normalize-space(ns:dados)">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center"> 
                            <xsl:value-of select= "ns:num_mesas" />
                        </td>
                        <td align="center"> 
                            <xsl:value-of select= "ns:num_pessoas" />
                        </td>
                        <td align="center"> 
                            <xsl:value-of select= "ns:hora_abertura" />
                        </td>
                        <td align="center"> 
                            <xsl:value-of select= "ns:hora_fechar" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <tr>
                        <td>DONT EXIT RESTAURANT <xsl:value-of select= "@id_hotel" />  </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to your input data (with the namespace attribute added as above), will produce this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table xmlns:ns="your-namespace">
   <tr>
      <td align="center">10</td>
      <td align="center">3</td>
      <td align="center">11:30</td>
      <td align="center">23:00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>DONT EXIT RESTAURANT </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

You can test and verify the result **[here](http://xsltransform.net/gWcDMew)**.